# ColdFusion not installing on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4

Tags: linux, coldfusion

When I was trying to install ColdFusion on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4, the installation script incorrectly report a warning regarding the C++ compatibility pack.
I dont know why its happening any solution?

Comment: This is probably better asked on Server Fault, which I think is why people are voting to close it...

Comment: what version of ColdFusion? CF10 only supports Red Hat 5.6 or 6.1

Comment: @Matt Busche im using Codlfusion 8 actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the adobe coldfusion website. they said...

> If you plan to use Verity or C++ based custom CFX tags, you should
>   interrogate your system for compat-libstdc++ and glibc packages and
>   install them if necessary. Either query all packages and use the grep
>   command as a filter or query the exact package name. For example, the
>   command rpm -qa | grep compat-libstdc++ queries all packages and
>   filters or greps on the string compat-libstdc++. This command might
>   produce two results, compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-47.3 and
>   compat-libstdc++-296-2.96-132.7.2.